# Посчитать количество элементов в квадратной матрице

Tags: c++, функции

```
88 3 9 104
55 44 99 101
2 3 6 777
99 0 21 333
```

Нужно подсчитать количество элементов в строке матрицы. Но считает не правильно (пишет ответ 7, когда элементов 4). И выдает неизвестную ошибку сценария.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void ElMatrix(int &n)
{
    char t = ' ';
    ifstream F;
    F.open("matrix.txt");
    F.get(t);
    while (t != '\n')
    {
        F.get(t);
        if (t != ' ')n++;
    }
    F.close();
}

int main()
{
    int  n(0);

    ElMatrix(n);

    cout << n;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в  текстовом файле находятся однотипные элементы, то подсчитать количество элементов можно в одну строчку. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

//...


std::ifstream f( "matrix.txt" );

size_t n = std::distance( std::istream_iterator<int>( f ), 
                          std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

В результате переменная `n` будет хранить число записанных целых чисел в текстовом файле.

Или вы могли бы сами написать цикл, как говорится, вручную. Например,

```
int x;
while ( f >> x ) ++n;
```

Если вы хотите поупражняться с посимвольным чтением текстового файла, то лучше объявить вашу функцию следующим образом

```
size_t ElMatrix( const char *file_name );
```

и вызывать ее как

```
size_t n = ElMatrix( "matrix.txt" );
```

Само определение функции может выглядеть следующим образом

```
size_t n = ElMatrix( const char *file_name )
{
    std::ifstream is( file_name );

    size_t n = 0;
    bool is_space = true;

    for ( int c; ( c = is.get() ) != std::char_traits<char>::eof() &&
                 c != '\n'; )
    {
        bool not_is_space = !(c == ' ' || c == '\t');
        n += is_space && not_is_space;
        is_space = !not_is_space;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Что вы вообще считаете?
Вы пропускаете первый символ, а далее считаете все символы в строке, не являющиеся пробелами.

Для приведенной вами строки вполне корректно выдает 30.

Что заказали - то и получили...

Кстати, зачем вы вообще делаете это функцией - в которую благополучно вставляете вообще все - и открытие файла (без проверки корректности, кстати...), и подсчет непробельных символов. Функция должна заниматься одним логически отдельным делом.

Comment: я не знаю, но редактор отказывает записывать матрицу. Строка чисел - нужно каждые четыре элемента записать в разных строках - редактор мне отказал. Я должен подсчитать количество элементов в строке. Я уже понял, что считает каждый символ. А как подсчитать количество чисел в строке матрицы? Как исправить?

Comment: Считывайте целые числа, а потом берите квадратный корень :)